# Error - Java socket with the local IP (not the localhost ip)

Tags: java, sockets, udp

When I try to make a socket using the my local IP ( not the localhost ) I get this error:

```
Failed to bind UDP channel to endpoint [/172.25.1.20:11111]
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
```

Here is the code:

```
DatagramSocket dsocket = new DatagramSocket(null);
dsocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("172.25.1.20", port));
```

I'm using Windows 8 and my firewall is turned off.

Any ideia?

Comment: have checked whether port 11111 is in use by another process?

Comment: @ThomasStets Yes, I checked with a `netstat` command and it is not in use.

Comment: @EJP it _is_ an RFC 1918 IPv4 address; 172.16.0.0/12 are all RFC 1918

Comment: There are two possible problems that may cause this error. The IP address is not assigned to a local interface or the port is already bound. Please double check that and eventually provide results of `ip addr` and `netstat -an|grep 11111`.